# is it possible to hide the hourglass during a $http.get request?

Tags: angular, get, hide, clock

I have an $http.get request that takes a while to be finished. During its execution, the hourglass is shown on the screen, preventing the user to use it.

Can I simply hide the hourglass meanwhile the request is being processed?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can do that. You can hide the hour glass.

Comment: ok, could you please tell me how? thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you paste your code what you have ? So that I can take a look at it. Suggest accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can create boolean isLoad, set it true while executing function and set it false when finished. 
So this flag can help you set CSS.

if you use Observable :

```js
GetSomething():void {
  this.isLoad = true;
  this.apiMethod().subscribe(data=>{
    //do something with data
    this.isLoad = false;
  });
}
```

if you use calbacks:

```js
GetSomething():void {
  this.isLoad = true;
  this.apiMethod(data => {
    //do something with data
    this.isLoad = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm not in my office right now, but I'll try to explain what i'm doing.

Comment: I'm not in my office right now, but I'll try to explain what i'm doing.          html: <div> <span id='someid'> hello </span>  </div>                                                       javascript: $("#someid").hide();                                                                it works great on some elements of the DOM, but not specifically on the one I want, i.g., the hourglass id.